# How to draw random rectangles in Objective-C for iOs?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want do create a class, let’s call it `CustomView`, in which I write a custom method for creating rectangles. The position and size of the rectangles should be based on random numbers.

This is what my `CustomView` looks like so far:

CustomView.m

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation ShadowView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 100;
    int r1 = smallest + arc4random() %(largest+1-smallest);
    int r2 = smallest + arc4random() %(largest+1-smallest);

    int smallest2 = 0;
    int largest2 = 300;
    int r3 = smallest + arc4random() %(largest2+1-smallest2);
    int r4 = smallest + arc4random() %(largest2+1-smallest2);

    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(r1, r2, r3, r4);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);
}

@end
```

CustomView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ShadowView : UIView

@end
```

Now when I try to call this method in ViewController.m via `[CustomView drawRect]` I only get errors? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW - why is a class named `ShadowView` defined in a file named `CustomView`? They should match to avoid confusion.

Comment: It was a mistake, it should read ShadowView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `drawRect:` on `ShadowView`.

What you need to do is create an instance of a `ShadowView`, and add it to some parent view. That's it. You do not call `drawRect:` yourself.

```
ShadowView *view = [[ShadowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 50)]; // whatever frame you need
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

However, this doesn't make a lot of sense given your implementation of `drawRect:`. It seems what you are trying to make is a rectangle of a random size and position and then filled with white and having a black border.

Here's another idea. Change the `init` method of your view to give itself a random frame.

In CustomView.m:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 100;
    int r1 = smallest + arc4random_uniform(largest+1-smallest);
    int r2 = smallest + arc4random_uniform(largest+1-smallest);

    int smallest2 = 0;
    int largest2 = 300;
    int r3 = smallest + arc4random_uniform(largest2+1-smallest2);
    int r4 = smallest + arc4random_uniform(largest2+1-smallest2);

    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(r1, r2, r3, r4);

    return [super initWithFrame:rectangle];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
}
```

Now, create and add the view as follows:

```
ShadowView *view = [[ShadowView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Also note the use of `arc4random_uniform` instead of `arc4random`.

Lets say you wanted to add 5 of these random rectangles, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ShadowView *view = [[ShadowView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
I adapted the code according to your suggestions but I get a few errors: in drawRect, Line 1+2 `Use of undeclared identifier context`
Line 3+4 `Use of undeclared identifier rectangle`

`CustomView.m` is a subclass of `UIView`, is this right?

Comment: Fixed a few typos/copy&paste issues. And everywhere I said "CustomView" I meant "ShadowView".

Comment: Again thank you for your help!
I have one more question:
I would like to have one fixed frame (the size of the screen) and then add random generated rectangles (filled with random colors) to it.  Could I write a method where I within this the ShadowView class that does all of that?

Comment: Just use the `initWithFrame:` method (instead of `init`) to create your `ShadowView`. Pass in a `CGRect` with the size you want.

Comment: In the for-loop I used the following:

`CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 405, 725);`   
`ShadowView *view = [[ShadowView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`

The problem now is, that the entire screen is automatically filled with one trinagle.

Comment: Don't do that in the loop. Just do it for one `ShadowView`.